# How to disable "safe write" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to fix this issue on my dev setup: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6744

They suggest to disable "safe write" in my IDE, which is Visual Studio Code Version 1.10.2.

Does anybody know how to do it? I couldn't find anything about it so far.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `node-sass` bug, fixed on `4.9.2`:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1894#issuecomment-390199128

Answer (score 22):

"We do not have atomic saving in VS Code. File writes go directly into the file."
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28927

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it must be something else then.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also using Visual Studio

Comment: According to [this site] (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209768/saving-changes-does-not-trigger-watchers-saving-sa.html), Visual Studio (not VS Code) uses a sort of safe writing, although despite tried saving the the files in notepad.exe with no success.

Comment: Sorry, didn't dig any deeper into that. One thing that generally helped was to increase the memory allocation in your console like so: set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096